# Qt in VS 2015 comm edn

Tags: qt5.8

Hi i am getting the following error while building Qt application Test2 in Visual Studio 2015 comm. edn.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Test2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Moc'ing test2.h...
1>  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
1>  Uic'ing test2.ui...
1>  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
1>  Rcc'ing test2.qrc...
1>  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error 
MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 123.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.